# Guys i. Am getting this error while trying to install slither Can anybody tell me the reason of this error and how can i fix this

Tags: solidity, slither

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp